# Add row to table while incrementing primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table that looks like:

```
ID    Name   Age   Co
1     Adls   15    US
2     sldkl  14    FR
3     sldke  16    UK
4     sldee  17    IN
```

I want to add values to the table and have the ID incremented. ID is the primary key, and I set is Identity under column properties to 'Yes' and identity increment to 1.

So basically, I am doing:

```
Insert Into TableName(Name, Age, Co)
Values(slkdje, 19, CH)
(sldjklse, 20, AU)
(slfjke, 12, PK)
```

But, I am getting errors that the primary key is null, and therefore this operation in invalid. How would I add the values, but get the primary key values to increment?

Comment: There is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` you can set on a column, see: [Auto Increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName` give? Please add to your question...

Comment: There's no 'column properties' in MySQL . You must be using some kind of 'front end' application

Comment: @Strawberry ya, I didn't know the difference earlier. Its just regular sql. I'm using Microsoft Sql  Server

Comment: Some how your identity did not stick.  Check it again.

Comment: @J.Doe There is no such thing as "regular sql", every single DB is different. Specifically to sql server, what's the result of `sp_help TableName`?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right click that table, go to "Script Table As" and select "CREATE to". This will give the script for the table creation. Please add that into this post.

Comment: Use AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1):

here is a great example for what you want [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

here is also a sql query that is copy and paste that will show my example.

```
create table #temp(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
)
 insert into #temp(LastName) values('billy'),('bob')
select * from #temp

 drop table #temp;
```

hope this helps dude.